# Configuration sometimes not being injected

Tags: java, spring

I have 2 services, A and B, which are both dependent on library C.

At C, I created a configuration class:

```
@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "a.b-d.k")
public class K {
    private Map<String,String> k;

    public void setK(Map<String, String> k) {
        this.k= k;
    }

    public Map<String, String> getK() {
        return c;
    }
}
```

and then I inject it at the class D (in library C):

```
@Autowired
private K k;
```

Now, here is the issue:

I have a flow in which service A calls (synchronously) class D, and the configuration is injected just fine.

As part of the flow, there is an asynchronous call to service B, and service B also uses class D, only now the configuration is not present. Always null.

Both services have the @EnableConfigurationProperties annotation.

What could be the cause for such behavior?

Comment: To start, `@EnableConfigurationProperties` belongs on configuration classes, not services. Second, try replacing field injection with constructor injection and see if you find your problem (often at a non-Spring instantiation site).

Comment: If you could post a minimal reproducible example, you'd get an answer much faster.

Comment: @chrylis-cautiouslyoptimistic- Good to know about the annotation. Thanks. I posted below the cause for the above behavior.

Answer (score 0):

So the issue was not technical - the structure of my project got me confused.

I thought that once I deploy a spring app, classes are being built and then used by the different services - so for the example above only 1 D class is built and then being used by each service that is dependent on this library, where in fact each service creates a copy of its own of that same bean, so each service must inject its configurations independently - and that was missing in service B.

My project is a monolete that is divided to services by domains. The fact that it is a "monolith" got me confused.